Get the requirements info from a conan recipe file
I have a lot conan recipe files in the below format (the name of class in each of the conanfile.py is different)
conanfile.py is as below
from conans import ConanFile, CMake, tools
import os
from conan_settings import MySettings

class MyConan(ConanFile):
    """SW package conan class."""
    name = "check"
    description = "<Dummy>"
    license = MySettings.LICENSE
    url = MySettings.URL

    exports = "conan_settings.py"
    settings = "os", "arch", "compiler"

    # Add smart base logic
    python_requires = MySettings.base_class
    python_requires_extend = "smart.smartBase"

    options = MySettings.options
    default_options = MySettings.default_options

    def source(self):
        """Conan source method."""
        git = tools.Git()
        output = git.clone(self.url)
        self.output.info("Source: %s" % output)

    def requirements(self):
        """Load requirements."""
        for entry in MySettings.requirements:
            self.requires(entry)

    def build_requirements(self):
        """Load build requirements."""
        for entry in MySettings.test_requirements:
            self.test_requires(entry)

    def _configure_cmake(self, definitions: dict = {}):
        """CMake configure."""
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.definitions.update(definitions)
        cmake.configure(source_folder=".", build_folder=self._build_dir)
        return cmake

    def build(self):
        """CMake build the package."""
        cmake = self._configure_cmake()
        cmake.install()

    def package(self):
        """Package all artifacts."""
        self.copy("*", src=self._bin_dir,
                  excludes=('**/test/*', '**/tests/*', 'test/*'))
        self.copy(os.path.join("share", "test", "*"), src=self._bin_dir)

The conan_settings.py is as below
class MySettings:
    """Conan settings class."""

    CONAN_USER = 'smart-ci'
    LICENSE = 'proprietary'
    URL = 'https://abc.def.com/SMART/_git/check'

    # conan base class requirement
    base_class = f'foobar/2.0.0@{CONAN_USER}/stable'

    # conan requirements
    requirements = [
        f'baz/[>=1 <=3]@{CONAN_USER}/stable',
        f'jam/[>=4 <=7]@{CONAN_USER}/stable',
    ]

    test_requirements = [
        f'dummy/[~1.12.8]@{CONAN_USER}/stable',
        f'data/[~1.0.4]@{CONAN_USER}/stable',
    ]

    # options
    options = {'DEF_VERSION': ['ert-11']}
    default_options = {'DEF_VERSION': 'ert-11'}



For these files, I want to get the requirements that are parsed. How do I achieve that?
The out put expected is
python_requires = 'foobar/2.0.0@smart-ci/stable'
python_requires_extend = "smart.smartBase"
requirements = [  'baz/[>=1 <=3]@smart-ci/stable', 
                  'jam/[>=4 <=7]@smart-ci/stable'  ]
test_requirements = [ 'dummy/[~1.12.8]@smart-ci/stable',
                      'data/[~1.0.4]@smart-ci/stable', ]

I tried using conan info but that gives the fixed versions that will be installed & not the ranges as in the recipe files. Can anyone help on how to achieve this?
Another recipe, just to give an idea about the kind of recipe files
conanfile.py is as below
from conanfile_constants import ConanSettings
from conans import ConanFile

class AnotherConan(ConanFile):
    name        = "laggy-platform"
    description = "laggy platform implementation"
    license     = ConanSettings.LICENSE
    url         = ConanSettings.URL
    exports     = "conanfile_constants.py"

    python_requires = (
        ConanSettings.regd_CONAN_BASE,
        ConanSettings.laggy_CONAN_BASE,
    )

    python_requires_extend = (
        ConanSettings.PYTHON_REQUIRES_EXTEND_BASE,
        ConanSettings.PYTHON_REQUIRES_EXTEND_SW,
    )

    requires = (
        ConanSettings.laggy_IPC,
        ConanSettings.laggy_BUILD,
        ConanSettings.laggy_SAFE_TAR,
        ConanSettings.laggy_PLATFORM_IF,
        ConanSettings.CORE_TYPES,
        ConanSettings.CRYPTO_API,
        ConanSettings.STM_PROJECT_IF,
        ConanSettings.FLATCFG_LIB,
        ConanSettings.LOG_FRAMEWORK_IF,
        ConanSettings.EXM_EXECUTIONCLIENT_LIB,
        ConanSettings.COM_COMMUNICATION_MANAGER,
        ConanSettings.regd_CRC_LIB,
    )

    def build_requirements(self):
        self.test_requires(ConanSettings.FLATBUFFERS)


    def package(self):
        self.copy("*", src=self._bin_dir, excludes=('tests/*', 'test/*'))
        self.copy(pattern=f"deployment-ruleset-{self.name}.yaml", dst="integration", src="integration", keep_path=False)


conanfile_constants.py is as below
class ConanSettings:
    """Conan settings class."""

    CONAN_USER = 'smart-ci'
    LICENSE = 'proprietary'
    URL = 'https://abc.def.com/SMART/_git/check'

    PYTHON_REQUIRES_EXTEND_BASE = "regd-conan-base.regdBase"
    PYTHON_REQUIRES_EXTEND_SW = "laggy-conan-base.UcmregdSW"

    # pinned versions
    regd_CONAN_BASE = f"regd-conan-base/2.0.0@{CONAN_USER}/stable"
    laggy_CONAN_BASE = f"laggy-conan-base/1.1.0@{CONAN_USER}/tools"

    # variable versions
    laggy_BUILD = f"laggy-build/[^1]@{CONAN_USER}/stable"
    regd_FS_CLI = f"regd_fs_processor_cli/[^10]@{CONAN_USER}/stable"
    laggy_IPC = f"laggy-ipc/[^4]@{CONAN_USER}/stable"
    laggy_SAFE_TAR = f"laggy-safe-tar/[^5]@{CONAN_USER}/stable"
    laggy_PLATFORM_IF = f"laggy-platform-if/[^3]@{CONAN_USER}/stable"
    laggy_SWP_GENERATOR = f"laggy-swp-generator/[^3]@{CONAN_USER}/stable"
    regd_CRC_LIB = f"regd_crc_lib/[^3]@{CONAN_USER}/stable"


This is not possible in Conan 1 (btw, you are still quite legacy tools even for Conan 1, they can be replaced for the new ones, while staying in Conan 1), but Conan 2 serializing format will output more thorough information.
